# C#のインターフェースについて

Tags: c#

下記コードのビルドが通らず困っています。

```
public class TestClass : IBase, IExpansion1, IExpantion2
{
    public T Get<T>() where T : IBase
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public interface IBase {}
public interface IExpansion1 : IBase {}
public interface IExpantion2 : IBase {}
```

具体的には *return this;* のところで型変換ができないと怒られます。

思惑としては、
他のクラスがTestClassの機能を使うのに実体そのまま使うのではなく、
利用クラスごとに適切なinterface（IExpansion1, IExpantion2）を取得し、
それを通して使って欲しいと考えています。

その中で、interfaceの提供に一々メソッドを作るのもなんだかなと思うので、
ジェネリックなGetメソッドを作りIBaseで型制約をかけようとしたのですが、
うまくいきません。

まず、これがビルドが通らない理由ですが
「TestClassが全てのIBaseを実装/継承しているclass/interfaceを継承/実装しているとは限らないから」
なのかなと思ったのですが、その認識は正しいでしょうか？

そうだとしたら、上記のような思惑がある場合、どのような設計にしたら良いのでしょうか？
interface一つ一つに取得メソッドを作るしかないのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

一度アップキャストすれば変換可能です。

```
return (T)(object)this;
```

### 追記

型安全ですが現状のC#でビルド時に検出するのは難しいです。次期バージョンなら出来なくはないですが。

実行時に検出するための良くある仕様は「キャスト不能時に`null`を返す」という条件を増やすことです。その場合は

```
if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(GetType()))
{
    return (T)(object)this;
}
return default(T);
```

や、あるいは`T`に`class`制約を付けて

```
return this as T;
```

と実装します。

Comment: ビルド通りました！
ありがとうございます。

ただ、一度objectを通すことで型安全が断ち切られてると思うのですが、型安全なままキャストすることは出来ないのですかね…。

なんにせよ動くことは動いたのでありがとうございます。

Comment: なるほど、現状では難しいですか…。
キャスト不能時に`null`を返すのは良いですね。
`class`制約の方は、`interface`として提供したいので今回は避けたいです。
勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @ksr そうですか。参考までにお伝えしますが、型引数に`class`制約が付いていてもインターフェイスは指定可能ですので…

Answer (score 4):

TestClassがキャスト可能な型は、TestClass、IBase, IExpansion1, IExpantion2,objectの5種類です。

```
public T Get<T>() where T : IBase
{
    return this;
}
```

これだと、TはIBaseを継承したクラス何でも指定可能なので、上記以外の型も指定できてしまいます。
その為ビルドエラーになっています。

標準のas演算子でキャスト可能か調べる事ができますが、これでは駄目でしょうか？
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cscsdfbt.aspx

```
var test = new TestClass();
var base = test as IBase;
var expansion1 = test as IExpansion1;
var expansion2 = test as IExpansion2;
```

（キャスト不可能な型を指定した場合の結果はnull）

Comment: なるほど、確かに実体をasで変えるので良いですね。
なぜかメソッドで取得する事ばかり考えていました。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: ただ、取得と同時に何かの処理を行いたい場合もあるかとは思うので、メソッド方式で取得できる手段があると良いなと思うのですが、難しいですかね…。

Answer (score 0):

> 「TestClassが全てのIBaseを実装/継承しているclass/interfaceを継承/実装しているとは限らないから」
>   なのかなと思ったのですが、その認識は正しいでしょうか？

そういう理由ではありません。`where`はあくまでクラス継承、インターフェース実装しか保証できません。

```
class Other : IBase {}
```

が存在するとして

```
TestClass t;
Other o = t.Get<Other>();
```

に失敗するのはわかりますよね？

Comment: はい、わかります。
なので、失敗するからこそビルド出来ないのかな、と考えました。

whereで「複数の制約のうちのいずれかを満たす」って表現出来るとやりたいことができるのですが…。

Comment: "利用クラスごとに適切なinterface（IExpansion1, IExpantion2）を取得し、" というのは、どういうことでしょうか?　
`public void Hoge(IBase target) { /* target に何かする */ }` のように、処理を提供する側がインターフェイスを対象に処理を行うのでは不十分ですか?

Comment: 他のクラスが振る舞いを決めるための情報提供を`TestClass`は行いたいのですが、他のクラスの全てが`TestClass`全体が見える必要はないので、他のクラス毎に見える情報を制限したい→適切なinterfaceを切ってそれぞれに合う情報を取得して欲しい、と考えています。
ですので、IEnumerableやIDisposableのように「可能な操作を表す」というよりは、「個別クラス向けのAPI定義」に近い感じです。
他クラスが適切なinterfaceを使ってくれる保証は無いのですが、情報整理の面からやらないよりは良いと思ってしています。（相手クラス単位でアクセス制限かけられればより良いのですが…）